# NGINX Config: How to match any filetype or subfolder of given path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I need to bypass rails via NGINX for any requests that fall beneath a certain path for various assets such as:

```
test.com/inc/js/test.js
   -> /var/www/test/public/example/inc/js/test.js

test.com/inc/js/another/subfolder/test.js
   -> /var/www/test/public/example/inc/js/another/subfolder/test.js

test.com/inc/css/test.css
   -> /var/www/test/public/example/inc/css/test.css

test.com/inc/css/any/given/subfolders/test.css
   -> /var/www/test/public/example/inc/css/any/given/subfolders/test.css
```

I am currently trying to edit the nginx config such that any web request maps to the appropriate file:

```
location ~* /inc {
    root /var/www/test/public/example/inc;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Which isn't working - I assumed that any request of `/inc` would then map accordingly, but I am clearly missing something? How can I map any requests to `/inc` to the correct corresponding path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that unless you really wanted to limit the location matching to JS and CSS files only, you don't even need a regexp for this, just redefining the root should be sufficient:

```
location /inc/ {
    root /var/www/test/public/example;
}
```

The matched `/inc/` from the request URI will be appended to the given root, together with anything after it. See an equivalent example under the `root` option in the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root). This should be much faster and resource-efficient than regexps.

If you *did* want to limit the match to JS and CSS files only, you'd indeed have to use a regexp:

```
location ~* /inc/.*\.(js|css) {
    root /var/www/test/public/example;
}
```

Comment: I see, so for example with the first solution, a request to `/inc/js/example/subfolder/test.js` would go to `/var/www/test/public/example/inc/js/example/subfolder/test.js`?

Thus in my initial attempt in the question, I should just have omitted the `/inc` from the root declaration? (and perhaps included a trailing slash for the location?)

Comment: Yes, exactly, see the linked docs, there is also an example that clarifies it fully I think.

Comment: Ah of course, this is perfect. I stupidly was editing the location within the `location /` block. Once taken out, this works perfectly and definitely seems like the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it just took a bit of brushing up on regex and I managed to figure out the solution, if any regexperts out there could find anything more optimal, do indeed let me know:

```
location ~* \/inc\/(.*)\/*\.(js|css) {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```